# Como criar uma variável que receberá elementos de laço for e formará uma tupla

Tags: funções, contador, tupla

Srs.
Estou gerando uma função contador simples que mostra números a partir de um inicio até um fim em passos. Já consegui fazer essa função utilizando *While*, porem agora estou tentando com o for in range.

```
def contador(i, f, p):
    for c in range(i, f, p):
        #preciso de uma variável que acumule os valores(10, 20, 30...100)
    # retorne a variável com a tupla(10, 20, 30...100)


variável=contador(10,100,10)
print(variável)
```

espero que eu tenha sido claro com a dúvida. Obg.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso da seguinte forma:

```
def contador(i, f, p):
    numeros = [] #cria uma lista vazia que será usada para armazenar os números.
    for c in range(i, f, p):
        numeros.append(c) #insere um número na lista a cada iteração do laço for.
    numeros = tuple(numeros) #converte a lista para tupla através da função tuple.
    return numeros

variavel=contador(10,100,10)
print(variavel)
```

Comment: Perfeito, era o append que queria. Obrigado!

Comment: @PedroGuerreiro Na verdade nem precisa dessa lista, dá pra criar a tupla a partir do `range`, ou seja, a função poderia ser apenas `return tuple(range(i, f, p))` - veja: https://ideone.com/GnflKQ